# hide a prop from user view in typescript react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create two components, one of them can (or maybe it just must) be used inside the other one. something like this:

```
Interface IChild {
  name: string;
  childKey?: string;
}
const Child: React.FC<IChild>= ({name,childKey})=>{
 // do something here
}
```

```
Interface IParent {
}
const Parent: React.FC<IParent>=({children})=>{

return (
  <div>
       {React.Children.map(children, (child, index) => {
        const item = child as ReactElement<PropsWithChildren<IChild>>;

        if (item.type === Child) {
          return cloneElement(item, { childKey:uuid() });
        } else {
          return child;
        }
      })}
  </div>
)
}
```

Usage:

```
const App:React.FC<> = ()=>{
return (
    <Parent>
      <Child name="john"/>
      <Child name="jane"/>
    </Parent>
   )
}
```

So when the `Child` is used inside the `Parent`, `Parent` will add the `childKey` prop, and when it's not used inside the `Parent`,  `childKey` is not needed and is useless, I want to eventually publish this as a package, and don't want the end user to see the `childKey` prop, I just want to add it in case of `Child` is used inside the `Parent`, so the user should not see that prop. how can I do this? and should I do this?

Comment: Lol you might be able to also do this with some really anti pattern React context abuse.

Comment: Btw why `React.Element.map`? It should just be `children.map`?

Comment: where is React.Element.map inside my code?
where can I find about this patterns (anti patterns)?

Comment: Your `Parent` component has `React.Element.map` for some reason

Comment: do you mean `React.Children.map`?

Comment: Oh wait sorry I didn't know it was part of its API... Can you share what's not working then? Errors/expectations/behaviour/etc?

Comment: never mind, and every thing works right now, but I cannot hide the `childKey` prop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242367/discussion-between-youdateme-and-ako).

Comment: @Ako What is the intended purpose of the `childKey`?

Comment: it is used to check which element is clicked on, it is for this package here: https://github.com/ako-v/react-collapsible-accordion in Accordion and  AccordionItem components

Answer (score 1):

Probably the only way to do that is to wrap child in fragment and set fragment's key.

```
// Parent.tsx

import React from "react";
import { Child } from "./Child";

interface IParent {}

export const Parent: React.FC<IParent> = ({ children }) => {
  const childs = React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return null;
    }

    if (child.type === Child) {
      return <React.Fragment key={`UUID-${uuid()}`}>{child}</React.Fragment>;
    }

    return child;
  });

  return <div>{childs}</div>;
};
```

Then `if (child.key?.startsWith("UUID-")) { /* ... */ }`

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-engelbart-tbjtn1?file=/src/Parent.tsx:0-491)

Comment: Thank you, but the Child component uses that `chidkey`, but this way child is not aware of the key.

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you want to hide that prop for the Child